# This or that is/are?

Tags: conjunctions, singular-vs-plural

When you have something like:

> The cat or dog are/is called...

Is it "are" or "is" I am unsure as it could be either which makes it plural right?

What about these cases:

> The cats or dog ____ called...
>
> The cat or dogs ____ called...
>
> The cats or dogs ____ called...

And then the same for if it's "and" instead of "or".

Answer (score 9):

In the case of *and*, it's very simple. Regardless of whether the nouns are singular or plural, joining them with *and* "creates" plurality.

> The cat(s) and the dog(s) **are** under the bed.

Again, whether *cat* and *dog* are individually singular or plural will have no effect on the verb. The verb will consistently be plural following nouns joined by *and*.

*Or* is slightly more complex. Two nouns joined by *or* do not create plurality. Instead, **the verb will be made singular or plural by the noun closer to the verb.**

> The cat or the *dog* **is** under the bed.

In this first sentence, "dog" is singular and therefore we use the singular verb form "is."

> The cats or the *dog* **is** under the bed.

In this second sentence, you can see that *cats* is now plural, but the verb is unaffected. The verb form depends entirely on *dog* because it is the noun closer to the verb.

> The cat or the *dogs* **are** under the bed.

For this third sentence, now that *dogs* is plural, the verb changes to the plural form *are*.

Check **[here](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)** for a guide on subject-verb agreement, including what I covered about *and* and *or*.

Answer (score 0):

The verb is singular if both elements are singular, so:

> The cat or dog **IS** called

If one of them is plural, then the verb becomes plural:

> The cats or dog **ARE** called/ The cat or dogs **ARE** called

However, in some cases, people use proximity agreement => the nearest noun decides the verb

> The cat or **DOGS ARE** called
>
> The cats or **DOG IS** called

For the case **and**, the suitable verb here is ARE.

But if your subject is a proper noun or a name (title of a book or movie, for example), then IS should be used for both cases.